# CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: 2

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm developing a BLE app in iOS6. I got `CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: 2` when I call `readValueForCharacteristic` on a characteristic after it's set to notifying state.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error`

The delegate callback gets called with an unknown error from NSLog: `Error updating value for characteristic Unknown (<fef2>) error: Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error." UserInfo=0x1dd3b7e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error.}
```

Please give some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you cannot read the value of a characteristic that is set to notify.

You need to "subscribe" to notifications for that characteristic:

```
[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
```

The value can then be read in your delegate method:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

The BLE docs for iOS are quite poor in this regard.

Comment: Yes. You are right, error 2 means no read permission. I meet another issue, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14495120/1184525